# Spring - Create bean in XML with reference to Java bean, and the other way around

Tags: java, spring

If I have a bean created in Java, with @Bean, how do I reference this bean in XML when creating a bean there?
And if I have a bean created in XML, how do I reference this bean in Java when creating a bean there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a bean in Java class is equivalent to creating the bean in the XML file. So if you want to refer a bean created in Java class in an XML file, simply use `ref= beanName` attribute to refer the bean and vice versa.

**In the official documentation it says:**

**4.2.1. Declaring a bean**

To declare a bean, simply annotate a method with the @Bean annotation. When JavaConfig encounters such a method, it will execute that method and register the return value as a bean within a BeanFactory. By default, the bean name will be that of the method name.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new TransferServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

The above is exactly equivalent to the following appConfig.xml:

```
<beans>
    <bean name="transferService" class="com.company.TransferServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

Both will result in a bean named transferService being available in the BeanFactory/ApplicationContext, bound to an object instance of type TransferServiceImpl:

And also you need to make sure you add

```
<bean class="org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor"/>
```

in your xml so your XML configuration and Java configuration has same bean definitions if they are declared in different contexts.

And if you want to include your traditional bean configuration from XML to Java configuration, then you need to Import the XML resource to that class as below:

```
@ImportResource({"classpath*:your-configuration.xml"})
```

Comment: Also if you would like to read more about this I would suggest you to have a look at the official documentation:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html

Comment: This is the classic way... +1

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on the last Bean, the ConfigurationPostProcessor. What does it do, and why do I always need it when beans are declared both in Java and XML?

Comment: It is added to pick up all the beans declared in Java configuration from an XML file so as Spring container can pick and register those beans. However, you can also add <context:annotation-config/>  in XML file which will add all the postbeanProcessors including ConfigurationPostProcessor.

Comment: So if I declare å bean in XML with <bean>, and I want to reference this bean in a Java bean-declaration, then I need @ImportResource and <context:annotation-config/>? Or do I only need one of them? And if I want to reference a Java declared bean in an XML declaration, then I only need <context:annotation-config/>?

Comment: bean declaration in java and using them in XML:  you need <context:annotation-config/>(if registering all processors). 

bean declaration in XML and using them in Java: you need the ImportResource annotation

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Other answers only answer part of the picture. Let me try to summarize the big picture. The key point is that every bean has an identifier which is unique within the spring container. We can use this identifier to reference a bean.

The bean identifier can be configured by :

- XML                : `id` and `name` attribute in the `<bean/>`
- Java Config        :

  - `value` and `name` attribute in `@Bean` .
  - `value` attribute  in`@Component` and its stereotype annotation such as `@Service` , `@Controller` etc.

If the identifier is not configured explicitly , depending on how the beans are declared , a default one will be generated for them:

- For beans declared using XML, `@Component` and its stereotype , it is the class name of that bean formatted in *lowerCamelCase*.
- For beans declared using `@Bean` , it is the name of that bean method

To reference a bean declared in Java configuration in XML , use `ref` property to refer to its identifier such as :

```xml
   <bean name="foo" class="com.example.Foo">
        <property name="service" ref="bar"/>
    </bean>
```

So `service` property is reference to a bean which the identifier is called `bar`

To reference a bean declared in XML in Java , you can simply annotate `@Autowired` on a field. If there is only one spring bean which the type is the same as the type of this field (i.e. Bar in this case) , this bean will automatically be referenced and injected . It is called auto-wired by type which you does not require to reference it by the bean identifier :

```java
@Service
public class Foo {

   @Autowired   
   private Bar service;

}
```

On the other hand , if there are multiple beans which the type are also Bar, you have to use `@Qualifier` with the bean identifier to reference a particular bean among these Bar beans. This is called auto-wired by name :

```java
@Service
public class Foo {

   @Autowired   
   @Qualifier("bar123")
   private Bar service;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple Spring bean, Grandmother and add a reference to beans MotherBean and FatherBean.

**You have two approaches to do this:**

**First Approach**

GrandMother Bean:

```java
@Service("grandmotherBean")
public class Grandmother {

    @Autowired
    private MotherBean motherBean;

    @Autowired
    private FatherBean father;

}
```

Mother Bean here

```
@Service("motherBeanBean")
public class MotherBean {
public MotherBean() {

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return " it is me ! MotherBean";
}

}
```

Father Bean Here

```
@Service("fatherBeanBean")
public class FatherBean {
    public  FatherBean (){

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " it is me ! FatherBean";
    }


}
```

**And another way is you can configure Spring bean references directly to the `applicationContext.xml`**

**Second Approach**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    <bean id="Grandmother"
        class="com.dulaj.stack.Grandmother">
        <property name="FatherBean" >
            <ref local="fatherBeanBean"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="fatherBeanBean" class="com.dulaj.stack.FatherBean">
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding example, It really helped in understanding :)