# Connecting to mysql database using spring framework

Tags: java, spring, database

So I am very new to this Spring framework thing and I am trying to figure it out how to apply this bean

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kompiuteriu pardavimai" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

To my database connection class which have singleton

```
package DatabaseConnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class DBConnector { 
    
        protected static Connection con = null;

        private DBConnector(){
        }

        public static Connection getConnection() {
           try {
               if(con == null) {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kompiuteriu pardavimai", "root", "");
               }
           }catch(Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return con;
        }

}
```

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Comment: And have you resolved your issue and any answer were helpful for you?

Comment: I started learning spring boot :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are new in Spring, the best way is start using Spring Boot (less fancy configurations, easier and faster to code and learn than Spring). Spring Boot offer [JPA module](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa) cause working with database easier and pleasantly without playing with connections, connectors and other such things. [Some tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CX-xBVIEIkw).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check logs. We cant see what happend inside executing code.

It not Good have space in connection - kompiuteriu pardavimai, change this.

Use @Configuration annotation, and then u Can Inject this bean in class by bean name.

[Spring - Create bean in XML with reference to Java bean, and the other way around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848151/spring-create-bean-in-xml-with-reference-to-java-bean-and-the-other-way-aroun)